# Ran out of disk space on Google Cloud notebook, deleted files, still shows 100% usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, disk, diskspace

1. Processing a large dataset from a Google Cloud Platform notebook, I ran out of disk
   space for /home/jupyter:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  8.5M  3.0G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        99G   38G   57G  40% /
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      124M  5.7M  119M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb        492G  490G  2.1G 100% /home/jupyter
```

2. I deleted a large number of files and restarted the instance. And no change for /home/jupyter.

```
/dev/sdb        492G  490G  2.1G 100% /home/jupyter
```

3. Decided to explore this a little further to identify what on /home/jupyter was still
   taking up space.

```
$ du -sh /home/jupyter/
490G    /home/jupyter/
```

```
$ du -sh /home/jupyter/*
254M    /home/jupyter/SkullStrip
25G     /home/jupyter/R01_2022
68G     /home/jupyter/RSNA_ASNR_MICCAI_BraTS2021_TrainingData
4.0K    /home/jupyter/Validate-Jay-nifti_skull_strip
284M    /home/jupyter/imgbio-vnet-cgan-09012020-05172021
4.2M    /home/jupyter/UNet
18M     /home/jupyter/scott
15M     /home/jupyter/tutorials
505M    /home/jupyter/vnet-cgan-10042021
19M     /home/jupyter/vnet_cgan_gen_multiplex_synthesis_10202021.ipynb
7.0G    /home/jupyter/vnet_cgan_t1c_gen_10082020-12032020-pl-50-25-1
(base) jupyter@tensorflow-2-3-20210831-121523-08212021:~$
```

This does not add up. I would think that by restarting the instance, the processes that were referencing deleted files would be cleaned up.

What is taking up my disk space and how can I reclaim it?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 1):

Disk was fragmented. Created  a new instance from scratch.